What is the difference between these two types of vectors of vectors (Julia)
I can define a "matrix" as a vector of vectors. i.e
vecMat = [[0,1],[1,2]]
If you run this in a jupyter notebook, this object is labeled as 2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}.
Now if I did:
newVecMat =  eachcol(reduce(hcat,vecMat)) 
that type of object is labeled as 2-element
ColumnSlices{Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, SubArray{Int64, 1, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Int64}, true}}
What is the difference between these two?
Is there anything I should be aware about (perhaps mistmatching types somehow)?
edit: fixed typo in definition of vecMat

Tip: next time describe the actual problem you want solve, not only your method of solution (see XY problem). It helps to address the problem. And also, you may use unsuitable tools.
In few words, Slice-objects are wrappers of arrays (vectors, matrices, etc) that helps to iterate through the array in a specific way. E.g. eachcol(M::Matrix) may be interpreted as an iterator over columns of matrix M.
Slice-objects are memory-effective. For example, eachcol(M) does not copy elements of matrix M, but stores views to columns of M.
julia> @allocated M = [1 2; 1 2]
96

julia> M
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 1  2

julia> @allocated VV = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]  # columns of M as vector of vectors
224

julia> VV
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1]
 [2, 2]

julia> @allocated EC = eachcol(M)  # also columns of M
32

julia> EC
2-element ColumnSlices{Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, SubArray{Int64, 1, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Int64}, true}}:
 [1, 1]
 [2, 2]

julia> EC == VV
true

As of awareness, some methods for Arrays (Vector, Matrix, ...) may not be implemented for slices in standard library. Though both slices and Arrays are subtypes of AbstractArrays.

Thanks! I was not looking to solve any specific problem, just wanted to know what this type was as I came across it.

vecMat = [[0,1][1,2]] will error anyway:

    julia> vecMat = [[0,1][1,2]]
    ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element Vector{Int64} at index [1, 2]
    Stacktrace:
     [1] getindex(::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
       @ Base ./essentials.jl:14


This isn't valid syntax for creating a vector of vectors. What you've written gets the 2-element Vector{Int64}:

    julia> [0,1]
    2-element Vector{Int64}:
     0
     1


and tries to index it along two dimensions with [1,2].
Take a look at these valid syntaxes:

    julia> x = [[1,2],[3,4]]
    2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
     [1, 2]
     [3, 4]
    
    julia> x = [[1,2];[3,4]]
    4-element Vector{Int64}:
     1
     2
     3
     4
    
    julia> x = [[1 2],[3 4]]
    2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
     [1 2]
     [3 4]
    
    julia> x = [[1;2],[3;4]]
    2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
     [1, 2]
     [3, 4]
    
    julia> x = [1 2 3 4]
    1×4 Matrix{Int64}:
     1  2  3  4
    
    julia> x = [1 2;3 4]
    2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
     1  2
     3  4


The Julia manual, and specifically, the section on Array Literals ought to be a good starting point for you to better understand what all of this means:

    julia> [1, 2, 3] # A 1-dimensional array (i.e. vector) of `Int`s
    3-element Vector{Int64}:
     1
     2
     3



If the arguments inside the square brackets are separated by single semicolons (;) or newlines instead of commas, then their contents are vertically concatenated together instead of the arguments being used as elements themselves.


Similarly, if the arguments are separated by tabs or spaces or double semicolons, then their contents are horizontally concatenated together.


Single semicolons (or newlines) and spaces (or tabs) can be combined to concatenate both horizontally and vertically at the same time.


Spaces (and tabs) have a higher precedence than semicolons, performing any horizontal concatenations first and then concatenating the result. Using double semicolons for the horizontal concatenation, on the other hand, performs any vertical concatenations before horizontally concatenating the result.

... and so on. Give the manual a quick read.

The Julia REPL comes with a very helpful feature to learn the language itself: you can look up the documentation of, e.g., a function by typing ?myfunction, e.g. ?reduce and ?hcat. This is also documented in the manual, and in the startup banner you get when you fire up the REPL.
Similarly, for eachcol:

    help?> eachcol
    search: eachcol eachslice eachmatch
    
      eachcol(A::AbstractVecOrMat) <: AbstractVector
    
    
      Create a ColumnSlices object that is a vector of columns of matrix or vector A. Column slices are returned as
      AbstractVector views of A.
    
      For the inverse, see stack(cols) or reduce(hcat, cols).
    
      See also eachrow, eachslice and mapslices.
    
      │ Julia 1.1
      │
      │  This function requires at least Julia 1.1.
    
      │ Julia 1.9
      │
      │  Prior to Julia 1.9, this returned an iterator.
    
      Example
      ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
    
      julia> a = [1 2; 3 4]
      2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
       1  2
       3  4
    
      julia> s = eachcol(a)
      2-element ColumnSlices{Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, SubArray{Int64, 1, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Int64}, true}}:
       [1, 3]
       [2, 4]


likewise:

    help?> ColumnSlices
    search: ColumnSlices
    
      ColumnSlices{M,AX,S}
    
    
      A special case of Slices that is a vector of column slices of a matrix, as constructed by eachcol.
    
      parent can be used to get the underlying matrix.
    
    help?> SubArray
    search: SubArray
    
      SubArray{T,N,P,I,L} <: AbstractArray{T,N}
    
    
      N-dimensional view into a parent array (of type P) with an element type T, restricted by a tuple of indices (of type
      I). L is true for types that support fast linear indexing, and false otherwise.
    
      Construct SubArrays using the view function.


Another helpful tool is the @edit macro which you can use to open up the code that would be executed when evaluating the expression passed, in the browser of your choice.
Doing so for eachcol would take you to base/slicearray.jl, and so on.
From the docstring (in the source code) for Slices:

An AbstractArray of slices into a parent array over specified dimension(s), returning views (emphasis mine) that select all the data from the other dimension(s).

Your only missing piece for the puzzle now is views. Take a look at the manual.

Yup. I had a typo in my first array. But thanks, the bit on views was helpful!
